# How do I get the main property of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm working on a site that pulls data from a third party site. My PHP pulls the data and responds with a really nice JSON object. 
I then use $.each to iterate over the object and sort through the data which works great. The problem is I dont know how to pull the main property.

Example JSON response:

```
{
    "1234": {
        "all_sales": {"11/12/2012":"1211.33","11/13/2012":"2012.45"},
        "sales_total":"323.78",
        "store_number":"1234",
    },
     "5678": {
        "all_sales": {"11/12/2012":"1211.33","11/13/2012":"2012.45"},
        "sales_total":"323.78",
        "store_number":"5678",
    },

}
```

1234 and 5678 are store numbers. 
What I want is to not need the store_number property and just know thats what it is. 
In PHP it would be something like:

```
for ($data as $store_number => $store_data){
    //do whatever
}
```

Im doing this for all sorts of reasons, but mainly so I can simply call data.1234 or build an array of sales for like a top 10. For now the store_number property lets me do this but its extra data that isn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for x in loops are the right tool for the job here. I like jQuery, but don't whip out the JQ-hammer when JavaScript has it covered.

```
var myObj = {
    "1234": {
        "all_sales": {"11/12/2012":"1211.33","11/13/2012":"2012.45"},
        "sales_total":"323.78",
        "store_number":"1234",
    },
     "5678": {
        "all_sales": {"11/12/2012":"1211.33","11/13/2012":"2012.45"},
        "sales_total":"323.78",
        "store_number":"5678",
    },

}

for (var x in myObj) {
    alert('property:' + x);
    alert('property.sales_total:' + myObj[x].sales_total); 
}
```

Comment: Might want to use `if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {}` also then :)

Comment: For an object literal? Not necessary to my knowledge.

Comment: @ErikReppen on rare occasions yes (Object.prototype.foo="bar")

Comment: @Ian Compared to an object created by a function constructor which could have properties from the constructor prototype defined as enumerable, which a typical literal wouldn't.

Comment: @Christophe. Good detail, but I don't cover people doing bad stuff. Better to become aware of it through exceptions so you can fix it.

Comment: @ErikReppen Right, I see what you mean, but I guess I was referring to what Christophe gave an example of. Who knows how often that would occur, but I did say "Might want to use" to see what you had to say about it :) And I agree, I like to lay stuff out and let it fail if others mess it up.

Comment: Client-side development: Keep throwing it at the wall and then fixing it until it stops breaking. Although this is more of a JS-best-practices thing you can become aware of through breakage I guess.

Comment: The for loop with "in" is definitely the better method but I didn't know the correct syntax and couldn't find any easy examples.

Comment: For each iteration of `for(var x in obj)` x is a property name and obj[x] is the value of that object property. Also really handy for examining core JS objects to see what kind of stuff they can do. object.property and object['property'] are two ways of accessing the same property but you can use brackets to drop vars into and for string names that aren't legal var names that wouldn't work with dot notation.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use the first argument of the `$.each` callback function:

```
var a = { "1234": { ... }, "5678": { ... } };

$.each(a, function(main, val) {
    console.log(main); // prints "1234" and "5678"
});
```

Comment: In my opinion using `$.each` is heavy handed here. Javascript provides the `in` operator that can be used in a native `for` loop. `for (var key in object) {}`

Comment: They said that they're already using `$.each` to iterate over the object in the question, which is why I used it in my answer. If they weren't already using it, I'd agree, just using `for` and `in` would be easier.

Comment: If the author answered it, it would bug me less than having 0 whereas the JQ answer gets 3+. It's getting kinda silly on the JQ vs JS front when JS is actually easier. No sour grapes @Xymostech or at JQ though.

Comment: This works for sure, I didn't realize you could pass them with the callback function. I would take this as the correct answer but using the plain for loop is a lighter approach.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want an array with the values '1234', '5678', etc.:

```
myArray=$.map(myJSON,function(value,key){return key;});
```

[Edit] On second thoughts, this might be closer to what you're after:

```
myArray=$.map(myJSON,function(value,key){
// do whatever
});
```

And as @Ian said in the comment, you might want to group all your processing in a single loop (either $.each or $.map as in my example).

Comment: I definitely like this too, and it's confusing how the OP is handling these loop(s), but it might make sense to combine all logic into one loop instead of just getting an array of the keys (depending on which works better for the OP). I only say this because they use the `for` loop example with PHP of just iterating over the keys (not storing them). I always love `map` though

Comment: Its confusing but because you cant sort objects I build arrays based on their sales totals and then I can sort that array into different orders, say DSC by sales total. Then I can call that sorted array and it returns the store number for that position so I can then call that store and get all of its data... I may be WAY over complicating it but its working pretty well at the moment..

Comment: @DennisSmolek it makes perfect sense... now that you explain your reasons :-). And my first snippet does exactly what you're looking for, in just one line!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var key in object) {
    console.log(key);
}
```